# How does a jQuery instance appear as an array when called in console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, javascript-objects

When entered into a JavaScript console, a jQuery object appears as an array. However, it's still an instance of the jQuery object.

```
var j = jQuery();
=> []
console.log(j);
=> []
console.log('test with string concat: ' + j);
=> test with string concat: [object Object]
j instanceof Array
=> false
j instanceof jQuery
=> true
```

How could one duplicate this with their own object?

--------- EDIT ---------

Thanks to ZER0 for figuring it out. Here's some example code to create an object that works just like jQuery in the console:

```
var Foo = function() {
  this.splice = Array.prototype.splice;
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);

  return this;
}

var f = new Foo();
=> []
console.log(f);
=> []
console.log('test with string concat: ' + f);
=> test with string concat: [object Object]
f instanceof Array
=> false
f instanceof Foo
=> true
```

Very cool.

Comment: I want my function to return itself, not an array (note: `jQuery() instanceof Array` returns false). However, I'd like it to *appear* as an array in the console.

Comment: you can't concatenate a string and an object

Comment: I'm not trying to. I'm simply demonstrating jQuery's behavior. My goal is to duplicate that behavior.

Also, you *can* concatenate strings and objects, so long as you set the toString() method on the object.

Comment: Could you put your own answer into its own answer, please? The question body is, well, for the question only ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe they have something like that:

```
// Adding items to an object like an Array:
var myObject = {splice : Array.prototype.splice};

Array.prototype.push.call(myObject, 1, 10, "foo");

// Getting items from an object like an Array:

alert(Array.prototype.slice.call(myObject, 0));

console.log(myObject);

alert(myObject);
```

Comment: That's cool, but the only issue here is that `Array.prototype.slice.call(myObject, 0)` doesn't return an instance of type `myObject`, it returns an instance of type `Array`. jQuery manages to keep the return value as a `jQuery` object (even though it appears in the console as an `Array`), which is useful because then you can call `jQuery` methods on it.

Comment: Ok, so if you want that, you need to expose the `splice` property to your object, because it's the property that `console.log` calls to display array-like object. Notice that this behavior is not consistent across tools and browsers, and also it works for `console` only – `alert` and other stuff are not affected (exactly like jquery does).

Comment: Well the goal is not simply to create an array-like object, but it's for the console to display the object *as* an array. Even if you create an object capable of being spliced, when logged to the console (`console.log(instanceOfMyNewObject)`) it displays as a generic JavaScript object with its list of properties and values.

Comment: Yes I understood, and adding `splice` doing exactly that. However, as I said, it depends by the browser: for instance, this code in Chrome works as you want, but not in the web console of Firefox. However, this is exactly the same behavior that we have with jQuery – it use this approach.

Comment: Of course, you have to add the elements in the way I described in the code above – with `push`, that add `length` property – otherwise it won't work, unless you add manually `length`.

Comment: Instance of is achieved with the new operator.  And as I said before, it's just an object with the right properties to look like an array.  It's not sorcery.

Comment: One caveat of this in the more recent versions of the Chrome browser is that any and all methods on the object will appear as members of the array-like display in the console.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `jQuery()` you aren't passing any arguments to the function so it is returning an empty object. WHen you pass a selector as argument it creates an object of the elements that match the selector

Comment: Yes, but it's not exactly an array, is it? It's a jQuery object: `jQuery('span') instanceof Array` returns false, but `jQuery('span') instanceof jQuery` returns true.

Comment: JQuery never returns an array

Answer (score 0):

The console makes it look like an array because it has array-like properties.  It has length and n keys using integers.

Comment: So any object with integer keys and a `length` property appears as an array in the console? Can you duplicate this with a custom object?

Answer (score -1):

It returns an empty array, because it did nothing - array of elements affected.

Proper way to inspect would be

```
console.log(jQuery);
```

if you would do

```
console.log(jQuery('div'));
```

you will see that it returns array of elements.

Comment: Yes, but how could I do this with an object of my own?

Comment: NudeCanalTroll, please explain your self a little better. Do you want to return an array from your function of affected elements or what?

Comment: No, read over my original question again. I want to create an object that behaves exactly like jQuery does. jQuery does *not* return an array, it returns an instance of itself: `jQuery(anything you want to put here) instanceof Array` is false.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis, he/she wants the output of his object to be `[]` when it is entered into the console on it's own, even though the object is not an array.

Comment: JQuery does not return an array.

Comment: I am curious to know the reason myself now :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're trying to see are your object's properties. If that's the case, you're inadvertently converting the object into a string when you append it to another string. Use the `,` operator instead of `+` to show the object properties instead of the "stringified" version of the object:

```
console.log('test with string concat: ', j);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to see the object properties. In fact, that's the default behavior that I'm trying to *avoid*. Instead, I want my object to appear as an array, even though it's not an array.