# My subclass of Array does not call super constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) I want to create my own subclass of `Array`

```
QArray = function() {
    Array.apply(this, arguments);
};
QArray.prototype = new Array();
QArray.prototype.constructor = QArray;
```

which works as expected, method invocation works, but the constructor does not chain to Array.

```
// test constructor chaining
q = new QArray('1', '2', '3');
assert.equals('1', q[0]);      // => undefined
assert.equals(3, q.length);    // => 0
q = new QArray(10);
assert.equals(10, q.length);   // => 0
```

This tests pass if I replace `QArray` with plain `Array`. Somehow `Array` seems to be a special case. (I run this in Rhino 1.6 which is Javascript 1.5.) How can I fix my custom subclass of Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method already inherits the array methods, you can use array methods which modify the keys, such as `Array.prototype.push`:

```
QArray = function() {
    if (arguments.length == 1) this.length = arguments[0]; // Array constructor
    else this.push.apply(this, arguments);
};
QArray.prototype = new Array();
QArray.prototype.constructor = QArray;

q = new QArray('1', '2', '3');   // => [1,2,3]
assert.equals('1', q[0]);        // => true
assert.equals(3, q.length);      // => true
q = new QArray(10);              // => [,,,,,,,,,]
assert.equals(10, q.length);     // => true
q instanceof QArray;             // => true
q instanceof Array;              // => true
```

I've once written a custom array implementation, which behaves like a true array (including `length` setter/getter). If you need inspiration, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854216/938089?how-to-create-a-constructor-which-behaves-like-a-true-array).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I could reimplement the `Array.prototype.constructor` logic. But why do I have to?

Comment: @PeterKofler Because the Array constructor does not modify the array, but creates and returns new one: `var a = [];Array.call(a) == a;` (false), opposed to `var a=[];Array.prototype.reverse.call(a)==a;` (true).

Comment: Thank you. This works with the constructor. All array methods work **but** `q = new QArray(); q[3] = 'mango'; q.length // => 0 instead of 4`, so the length is not updated when a new element is set with `q[]` directly.

Comment: @PeterKofler Length is a special property. If the length getter/setter is very important to you, see the answer which I've linked.