# Does the js console clobber the jquery $() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jquery and playing with it in the chrome js console.

I've been using the js console mainly to view js objects as it displays all the properties, methods, and inherited stuff in a neat little pick list.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here, but when I ran $(document) in the console it just returned the document dom object. I was hoping I would see a js object with a bunch of delicious jquery methods and properties. My thinking was that jquery wraps up the dom element passed to the $() function in an object and the console would output that object for my perusal.

Then I found there is a $() function the console uses to return a reference to a dom object. Is that function being used instead of the jquery function? I have a feeling I'm not getting how this works.

Comment: What's odd about this is doing `jQuery(document.body);` gives the same behavior.

Comment: @crush the correct behaviour. What do you expect the result in Chrome to be?

Comment: @BenM No, it returns a jQuery object, which happens to have properties set to indexes, and a length property set to the number of matched elements so that it can function like an array. It is **NOT** an array, though.

Comment: What I see from `$(document)` is `[>#document]`, where `>` is a disclosure triangle. Do you see something different?

Comment: [`jQuery()` — which can also be written as `$()` — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: Never mind, brain fart moment.

Comment: You're thinking of the Chrome (and, I think, Firebug) ability to refer to the currently-selected DOM node as `$0`.  That's a completely separate use of the `$` character and it does not conflict with jQuery or anything else. You can wrap a jQuery object around the currently selected node with `$($0)`.

Comment: @Pointy, Chrome does also have a wrapper for gEBI named `$` available to the console, try opening a new tab and typing `$` in the console. Actually it has a different value on `about:blank` and on Chrome's default "blank tab" page.

Comment: @DaggNabbit I get the global jQuery function when I do that in Chrome. I was on just some plain page that apparently uses jQuery. Maybe the console won't override the page `$` if it's already bound to something else.

Comment: @Pointy, do it in a tab where jQuery's not loaded ;)

Comment: @DaggNabbit yep just saw that :) OK well that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, jQuery clobbers the console's `$` function. Check it with `$ == jQuery`.

Try `dir($(document))` if you want to inspect the jQuery object rather than the DOM element. All the interesting stuff is in `__proto__`.

> does $(document) just return a dom object by default or does the console see a dom object in a javascript object and remove it? Still confused about how the console and javascript work together.

When `$` is jQuery, `$(document)` returns an array-like object with a `length` of 1 and `window.document` at index 0. Note that this object isn't *actually* an array, it's just *like* an array, and Chrome displays it like an array; in this case, the single "array element" is displayed between two brackets. You are probably just not noticing the brackets, and only seeing the single element between them.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657612/), any object with a `splice` property referencing `Array.prototype.splice` and a numeric `length` property is "array-like" enough for Chrome to display it as an array. You can test this by typing something like `{splice: Array.prototype.splice, 0: 'blah', length: 1}` into the console; it will display as `["blah"]`. Use `console.dir` to avoid this kind of thing.

Comment: console.dir() is exactly what I wanted, thanks. But just so I understand how the console works, does $(document) just return a dom object by default or does the console see a dom object in a javascript object and remove it? Still confused about how the console and javascript work together.

Answer (score 2):

The command line API function `$(selector)` is an alias for `document.querySelector()`. It's only accessible from the console, if you try to access it from the document it's going to be undefined:

```
<script>alert(typeof $)</script>
```

But when you include jQuery, the `$` function defined by jQuery overshadows the command line API function of the same name.

Comment: Btw, `$()` sometimes called "bling" function.